# Particular field should not only contains numeric value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a regular expression to be used with Validator in Rails for the condition that "Particular field (xyz) should not only contains numeric value."

Answer (score 0):

```
> 'Your String'.match(/^[^\d]+$/).to_a ###["Your String"]
> 'Your 123 String'.match(/^[^\d]+$/).to_a  ### []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the field value against `/\D+/` - that will match one or more non-digit characters. Be aware, though that spaces, periods, and other special characters are considered non-digit, so you may have to add to that, depending on any other special cases that you may need to test for.